# Cached Lookup Folder Missing in Win 2003 DNS

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

Getting set to decommission a Win2k Server that was originally the only DC on our domain.  I have since created 2 more Win2003 DC servers that will take over AD as well as DNS for the domain.  I recently began shutting down services one by one on the Win2K box and so far so good until I got to DNS.

There is a multi-function printer on our network that refuses to acknowledge any other DNS (for email) except the Win2k box.  As far as I can tell, the only difference that I can see between it and the Win2003 boxes is that there is no Cached Lookup Folder on either of the later.

EDIT - Ok, so there was one other difference and it seems to be more in play.  The Win2k Server was accepting DNS on all interfaces.  As soon as I set one of the Win2003 boxes that way as well, then email worked again.  So I guess my orignal question is now invalid.

<strike>Is this a function of it being the "elder" domain controller or did I simply miss something with the setup of the DNS on the Win2003 boxes?</strike>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cached Lookups folder is not visible by default in the W2K3 DNS MMC. From the MMC view menu select "Advanced"  for the Cached Lookups folder to be visible.

I'm doubtful that has anything to do with your printer.

Comment: Thanks for that tip joequerty.  I was not aware of the one.  Anyways, I'm trying to decide if I should update my question or just nuke this since it seems unrelated to my problem.  Of course, someone else might be able to use your info.

Comment: Glad to help. It looks like you found the solution, although it's hard to tell why that worked without knowing more about the TCP/IP configuration of both the printer and the DNS serves.